# vertically align pgfplots using subfigure

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I need to align my two plots. They seem to be anchored by something other than the text. Because one pgfplot has more text in the caption then the other, it offsets it. Please see image. I tried searching and I've seen examples of `floatrow` but for images (not pgfplots), I tried using `floatrow` but I get a timed-out error. Also, is there a way for both plots to share one legend, perhaps positioned at the bottom that spans across both plots (horizontally)?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95,trim left]
\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    scale only axis,
    xlabel={nm},
    ylabel={Abs},
    xmin=385, xmax=485,
    legend pos=south east,
    cycle list name=color list,
    legend columns=2,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left]

\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=0] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=2.3] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=3.5] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=5.2] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=7.8] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=11.7] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=17.6] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=26.3] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=39.5] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=59.3] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=88.9] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=133.3] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=200] {ST038deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=300] {ST038deriv.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$t_{initial}$ derivative abs. spectra}
\end{subfigure}     %second subfigure
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95,trim left]
\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    scale only axis,
    xlabel={nm},
    ylabel={Abs},
    xmin=385, xmax=485,
    legend pos=south east,
    cycle list name=color list,
    legend columns=2,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left]

\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=0] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=2.3] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=3.5] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=5.2] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=7.8] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=11.7] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=17.6] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot [densely dashed] table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=26.3] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=39.5] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=59.3] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=88.9] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=133.3] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=200] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=300] {ST041 re-check deriv.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$t \approx 96 hr$ derivative abs. spectra}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the optional argument for the `subfigure` environment, so images will be aligned by the top, bottom or centers. The possible values for the optional argument are `b`, `t`, or `c`. For example, with `b`:

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}

\end{subfigure}\hill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}

\end{subfigure}
```

A different alignment option can be obtained by using `\subcaptionbox` from the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package, which automatically aligns the sub-figures resp. sub-tables by their very first caption line:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\subcaptionbox{$t_{\text{initial}}$ derivative abs. spectra}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95,trim left]
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.45\textwidth,
    scale only axis,
    xlabel={nm},
    ylabel={Abs},
    xmin=385, xmax=485,
    legend pos=south east,
    cycle list name=color list,
    legend columns=2,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left]

\addplot coordinates {(400,0) (430,8)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{$t \approx 96 hr$ derivative abs. spectra}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95,trim left]
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.4\textwidth,
    scale only axis,
    xlabel={nm},
    ylabel={Abs},
    xmin=385, xmax=485,
    legend pos=south east,
    cycle list name=color list,
    legend columns=2,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left]

\addplot[blue] coordinates {(400,5) (470,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{A common legend for both plots}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

As for the other requirement, the common legend, since no other information was provided, I simply used `\caption`.