# Centering subcaptions in a tikz pgfplot subfigure environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, minipage, subcaption

I am having a difficult time centering subcaptions for a figure. The figure looks like the following:

[image]

But as you can see, the Panel A and Panel B subcaption are nowhere near being centered with respect to the figures.. I have tried adjusting the `\textwidth` but that has not solved the issue. The code I have been using is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h] 
\caption{xx}
\label{Results.Robustness.PeerGroupSize}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering Panel A: Median of \\ absolute percentage errors
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering Panel B: Arithmetic mean of \\ absolute percentage errors
\end{minipage} 
\smallskip

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=10,
            ymax=30,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={10,15,20,25,30},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBITDA,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,23.4632898)
(6,20.4912848911315)
(8,19.7941272)
(10,15.7218624120743)
(12,15.6345338)
(14,15.4406741633428)
(16,15.4401631698244)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,25.4512269)
(6,23.5460147506771)
(8,22.3693236)
(10,17.7072706410539)
(12,17.5781692)
(14,17.3986212969882)
(16,17.4559060690141)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBITDA,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,30.6131174198114)
(6,27.8664334441736)
(8,24.9642976036815)
(10,19.7197165671043)
(12,20.3774183287973)
(14,19.9618323030134)
(16,19.4966820355432)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,33.1199843373062)
(6,30.5860910892484)
(8,28.7186190352845)
(10,24.2360675844504)
(12,23.9748988701945)
(14,23.5838901306087)
(16,22.918033041404)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\\[3ex]
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=10,
            ymax=30,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={10, 15, 20, 25, 30},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBIT,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,24.190563764574)
(6,23.4632898)
(8,19.4770707)
(10,15.7218624120743)
(12,15.3981318040823)
(14,15.3189028455693)
(16,15.2300002750468)
    };
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,26.1805637429578)
(6,25.4512269)
(8,22.1033621)
(10,17.7528651760113)
(12,17.8042766446753)
(14,17.6018509482883)
(16,17.5561665659589)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBIT,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,30.1828945498625)
(6,30.6131174198114)
(8,24.7747031767237)
(10,19.7197165671043)
(12,19.1663236491184)
(14,18.8627815830674)
(16,18.548416507874)
    };
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,32.4846302346739)
(6,33.1199843373062)
(8,27.7291528562977)
(10,22.5727172210159)
(12,22.4200373120666)
(14,22.0372230131445)
(16,21.8049523810071)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\\[3ex]
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={15,20,25,30,35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=P/E,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,27.2405585033126)
(6,26.4912848911315)
(8,25.3931816)
(10,20.1458041214363)
(12,19.291469183723)
(14,19.041479576969)
(16,19.4927359925628)
    };

\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,28.9744076009443)
(6,28.2967998061087)
(8,26.6487741)
(10,20.3741607827884)
(12,20.7968307400288)
(14,20.6056723271187)
(16,20.7669914784084)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=20,
            ymax=40,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={20,25,30,35,40},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=P/E,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,33.8786615361488)
(6,31.8664334441734)
(8,28.4849253966817)
(10,27.0836861737795)
(12,25.3503999589568)
(14,25.9544593152303)
(16,25.4966820355432)
    };

\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,35.9456063203218)
(6,34.6421278213531)
(8,30.5464004812642)
(10,28.0957792109814)
(12,27.4009061891243)
(14,27.2852880957453)
(16,27.2918033041404)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aren't they centered w.r.t. the full thing, i.e. not just the boxes but the full plot including labels and so on on the left. Unfortunately your code is not fully compilable, it complains about `obscureblue` not being defined.

Comment: Yes, the subcaption for Panel A is centered aligned, if one considers the whitespace  and y-axis label. However, it does not look satisfactory and would be much better, if it was aligned w.r.t. the boxes. Note: I'll change the code to remove the raggedleft alignments.

Comment: You can put a `\captionof` in the title of the topmost figures, this will look as you may want it to look. My problem is that, after I define `obsureblue`, the output does not look like what you show.

Comment: @marmot - I tried putting the '\captionof' after '\begin{tikzpicture}' and '\begin{subfigure}' for both of the top figures, but it didn't work. It essentially deleted my graph..

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134260/how-to-automatically-align-subfloat-captions-to-xlabel-of-pgfplots?r=SearchResults&s=4|33.2899 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257156/vertically-align-pgfplots-using-subfigure?r=SearchResults&s=10|28.5785 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488926/subcaptions-not-centered-for-pgfplot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `axis description cs:` which allows you to place stuff relative to the axis rectangle. This coordinate system can be used to center the texts relative to the axis rectangles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\definecolor{obscureblue}{RGB}{39,70,182}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h] 
\caption{xx}
\label{Results.Robustness.PeerGroupSize}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
% \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
% \centering Panel A: Median of \\ absolute percentage errors
% \end{minipage}%
% \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
% \centering Panel B: Arithmetic mean of \\ absolute percentage errors
% \end{minipage} 
% \smallskip

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=10,
            ymax=30,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={10,15,20,25,30},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBITDA,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,23.4632898)
(6,20.4912848911315)
(8,19.7941272)
(10,15.7218624120743)
(12,15.6345338)
(14,15.4406741633428)
(16,15.4401631698244)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,25.4512269)
(6,23.5460147506771)
(8,22.3693236)
(10,17.7072706410539)
(12,17.5781692)
(14,17.3986212969882)
(16,17.4559060690141)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\coordinate (ttl) at (axis description cs:0.5,1.25) ;
\end{axis}
\node[anchor=south,text width=7cm,align=center] at (ttl) 
{Panel A: Median of \\ absolute percentage errors};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBITDA,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,30.6131174198114)
(6,27.8664334441736)
(8,24.9642976036815)
(10,19.7197165671043)
(12,20.3774183287973)
(14,19.9618323030134)
(16,19.4966820355432)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,33.1199843373062)
(6,30.5860910892484)
(8,28.7186190352845)
(10,24.2360675844504)
(12,23.9748988701945)
(14,23.5838901306087)
(16,22.918033041404)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\coordinate (ttr) at (axis description cs:0.5,1.25) ;
\end{axis}
\node[anchor=south,text width=7cm,align=center] at (ttr) 
{Panel B: Arithmetic mean of \\ absolute percentage errors};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\\[3ex]
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=10,
            ymax=30,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={10, 15, 20, 25, 30},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBIT,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,24.190563764574)
(6,23.4632898)
(8,19.4770707)
(10,15.7218624120743)
(12,15.3981318040823)
(14,15.3189028455693)
(16,15.2300002750468)
    };
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,26.1805637429578)
(6,25.4512269)
(8,22.1033621)
(10,17.7528651760113)
(12,17.8042766446753)
(14,17.6018509482883)
(16,17.5561665659589)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBIT,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,30.1828945498625)
(6,30.6131174198114)
(8,24.7747031767237)
(10,19.7197165671043)
(12,19.1663236491184)
(14,18.8627815830674)
(16,18.548416507874)
    };
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,32.4846302346739)
(6,33.1199843373062)
(8,27.7291528562977)
(10,22.5727172210159)
(12,22.4200373120666)
(14,22.0372230131445)
(16,21.8049523810071)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\\[3ex]
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={15,20,25,30,35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=P/E,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,27.2405585033126)
(6,26.4912848911315)
(8,25.3931816)
(10,20.1458041214363)
(12,19.291469183723)
(14,19.041479576969)
(16,19.4927359925628)
    };

\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,28.9744076009443)
(6,28.2967998061087)
(8,26.6487741)
(10,20.3741607827884)
(12,20.7968307400288)
(14,20.6056723271187)
(16,20.7669914784084)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            xmin=3.5,
            xmax=16.5,
            ymin=20,
            ymax=40,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=0},
            ytick={20,25,30,35,40},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=P/E,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,33.8786615361488)
(6,31.8664334441734)
(8,28.4849253966817)
(10,27.0836861737795)
(12,25.3503999589568)
(14,25.9544593152303)
(16,25.4966820355432)
    };

\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,35.9456063203218)
(6,34.6421278213531)
(8,30.5464004812642)
(10,28.0957792109814)
(12,27.4009061891243)
(14,27.2852880957453)
(16,27.2918033041404)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the geometry package to make the page wide enough and show the page frame (which you can of course undo by dropping `showframe`). As long as the nodes have a key like `text width` they also can host `\captionof` commands.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! A minor thing: Originally, I wanted to use '\raggedleft' to make sure Panel B was aligned to the right margin of the page. I am trying to center the entire figure environment, but putting '\centering' after '\begin{figure}' did not solve it. Is there another way?